# How to import custom python variables into python NOTEBOOK?

Tags: python, import, ipython, jupyter

Surprisingly, I found I cannot import custom python variables into ipython NOTEBOOK. However, it can be imported to ipython shell.

In `config.py`, `A = 100`.

In python NOTEBOOK,

```
import config
config.A
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-a03322ffb792> in <module>()
----> 1 config.LAYER

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'A'
```

In python SHELL,

```
>>> config.A
'100'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same test works for me in ipython.

I would make a very simple python module, e.g., test.py, with one declaration :

`A = 100`

and try the same thing

`import test
test.A`.

The other thing that I notice is that in cases where something is genuinely not declared in test.py, ipython's error will throw

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 test.B`

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'B'

without a reference to `test.LAYER`. What version of ipython are you running? I tested with IPython 4.0.0. (This information is output when you start up ipython.)

Comment: Don't mind the `layer'. I simply forget to convert it to some other random number like `A`.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. It is enough for me.